# Error in running "docker-compose up" : Invalid config, exiting abnormally

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have three different nodes that every one has docker with Ubuntu on it. I want to make Kafka cluster with these three nodes; In fact, I installed docker on each node with loading Ubuntu with on them. I configure `"zookeeper.properties"` in docker environment for "150.20.11.157" like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

For node 150.20.11.134, "zookeeper.properties" file in docker environment is like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

For node 150.20.11.137, "zookeeper.properties" file in docker environment is like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

Also, I setup "server.properties" like this, for node 150.20.11.157:

```
broker.id=0
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.157:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

"server.properties" for node 150.20.11.134 is:

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.134:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

"server.properties" for node 150.20.11.137 is:

```
broker.id=2
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.137:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

More over, every node has a "myid" file in "/tmp/zookeeper/data" of docker environment with its server id inside it.

To make a Kafka cluster of three node like this picture, I make a "docker-compose.yaml" file and a dockerfile for it.

[image: kafka with docker]

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    zookeeper:
       build: .
       command: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh 
       /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties
       ports:
        - 2186:2186
    kafka1:
       build:
        context: .
        args:
          brokerId: 0
        command: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh 
        /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/server.properties
        depends_on:
         - zookeeper
    kafka2:
       build:
        context: .
        args:
          brokerId: 1
        command: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh 
        /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/server.properties
        depends_on:
         - zookeeper
    kafka3:
       build:
         context: .
        args:
          brokerId: 2
        command: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh 
        /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/server.properties
        depends_on:
         - zookeeper
   producer:
       build: .
       command: bash -c "sleep 4 && /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka- 
       topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2186 --replication- 
       factor 2 --partitions 3 --topic dates && while true; do date | 
       /kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 
       kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092 --topic dates; sleep 1; 
       done "
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
        - kafka1
        - kafka2
        - kafka3
  consumer:
      build: .
      command: bash -c "sleep 6 && /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka- 
      console-consumer.sh localhost:9092 --topic dates --bootstrap- 
      server kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092"
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
        - kafka1
        - kafka2
        - kafka3
```

The problem is after "dockerfile build ." when I do "sudo docker-compose up" on each node. It does not run completely. Some of my log is in following:

> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,197] INFO Reading configuration from: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
>
> kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,426] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
>
> kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,702] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>
> kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,702] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,150.20.11.137:2186 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>
> kafka1_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:30,012] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
>
> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,240] INFO Resolved hostname: 150.20.11.137 to address: /150.20.11.137 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
>
> kafka1_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:30,486] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>
> kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,715] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Initializing a new session to 150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,150.20.11.137:2186. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
>
> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,241] INFO Resolved hostname: 150.20.11.134 to address: /150.20.11.134 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
>
> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,241] INFO Resolved hostname: 0.0.0.0 to address: /0.0.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
>   kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,720] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
>
> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,241] INFO Defaulting to majority quorums (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
>   kafka3_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:29,721] INFO Client environment:host.name=be08b050be4c (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
>
> zookeeper_1  | [2019-01-17 16:09:27,242] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
>   zookeeper_1  | org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties
>   zookeeper_1  |  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
>   zookeeper_1  |  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
>   zookeeper_1  |  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
>   zookeeper_1  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/zookeeper/data/myid file is missing
>   zookeeper_1  |  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:408)
>   zookeeper_1  |  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:152)
>   zookeeper_1  |  ... 2 more
>
> kafka1_1     | [2019-01-17 16:09:30,487] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,150.20.11.137:2186 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   zookeeper_1  | Invalid config, exiting abnormall

In fact, I configured Kafka cluster without using docker on every node and I could run Zookeeper and Kafka server without any problem. Kafka cluster was like this picture:

[image: Kafka cluster without docker]

Would you please tell me what I am doing wrong to config this cluser?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How your network is configurated, ? When I implement a liked architecture used a DNS and iptables/forward

Comment: Dear @Soleil, I say every thing in my question about configuring my network. Could you please tell me if you use docker? and how do you implement a linked architecture exactly? I changed "hosts" file and put every IP address on it but it did not change any thing.

Comment: every node shall has in docker two network interfaces , and forward packets to right interface

Comment: @Soleil would you please guide me how I can config network interfaces in docker?thanks. I tried to install iptable and opened 2186 port, but my cluster still cannot run correctly.

Comment: MACVLAN docker you can use to sub interfaces, you can use two ips for node or other option is that use two ports for ip, but you need iptables to forward to right port

Comment: @Soleil thanks, I will try that and put result here.

Comment: Try this https://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-vlan-configuration

Comment: remember that example has two networks, you need 3

Comment: It would be easier if you used Kubernetes to orchestrate and deploy these containers rather than rolling it manually on each machine

Comment: Dear @Soleil, I think my problem is because ports are not open. would you please tell me how to open a special port in docker environment? thanks.

Comment: like to , docker run -it -p 2000-6000:1000-5000/tcp

Comment: Dear @Soleil thank you for your suggestion. I run that  command but it takes a lot of time to open docker and I  cannot stop it even with "ctrl+c".

Comment: @Soleil, sorry to bother you, when I run "docker run -it -p 2186:2186/tcp -p 2888:2888/tcp -p 3888:3888/tcp ubuntu_image", the result of "sudo docker-compose up" is: **Address already used** and it cannot run zookeeper server. With "docker run -it ubuntu_image", the result of "sudo docker-compose up" is **INFO Socket error occurred: user/150.20.11.134:2186: Connection refused**. I do not know what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the docker-compose file and problem solved. Zookeeper and Kafka server run without any problem. Topic was created. Also,Consumer and Producer worked with topic in three nodes. My docker-compose for one node is like this:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
   zookeeper:
     image: ubuntu_mesos
     command: /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh 
     /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties
     environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2186
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 
      0.0.0.0:2888:3888;150.20.11.134:2888:3888;150.20.11.137:2888:3888
    network_mode: host
    expose:
    - 2186 
    - 2888
    - 3888
    ports:
    - 2186:2186
    - 2888:2888
    - 3888:3888

kafka:
    image: ubuntu_mesos
    command: bash -c "sleep 20; /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-server- 
    start.sh /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/config/server.properties"
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
     KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 
     150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,150.20.11.137:2186
     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.157:9092
   expose:
      - 9092
    ports:
      - 9092:9092      

producer:
    image: ubuntu_mesos
    command: bash -c "sleep 40; /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-topics.sh -- 
    create --zookeeper 150.20.11.157:2186 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 
    3 --topic testFlink -- /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-console- 
    producer.sh --broker-list 150.20.11.157:9092 --topic testFlink"
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka

consumer:
    image: ubuntu_mesos
    command: bash -c "sleep 44; /root/kafka_2.11-2.0.1/bin/kafka-console- 
    consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 150.20.11.157:9092 --topic testFlink -- 
    from-beginning"
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
```

Two other nodes have the docker-compose like above too. 
Hope it was helpful for others.